# is there any way by which we can go back to try block from catch

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running a code in Selenium webdriver and whenever an element is not found it goes to catch. But I want java to continue the execution after skipping that element.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ast.LabeledStatement;

import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException;
import com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos.FieldDescriptorProto.Label;
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.GOTO;

public class try_zencart {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://ipadress/"; //I am providing an ip adress
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testTryZencart() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/zencart/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=1_16");
    try{
    int x = 3;
    int y = 0;
    driver.navigate().refresh();
    while(x<10){
    y=y+1;
    System.out.println("We have now started the " + y + "  iteration, which means that whenever we stop the execution the {$y} iteration was going on.");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/div/div/div/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/div/div[2]/div/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div/a[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div/a[3]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[12]/div/a[4]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[5]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[6]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[7]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[8]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[9]")).click();
    driver.navigate().refresh();
 }
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        System.out.println("\nArjun no good!!");
        driver.navigate().refresh();
    }
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

so now I want the execution to go back to try block after firing the exception. Is there anyways to do so.

Comment: Why don't you just `try`/`catch` within the `while` loop?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, your replies were valuable. and yeah it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `try/catch` block **inside** the `while` loop:

```
while (x < 10)
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

BTW, you should also increment `x` inside the loop...

Comment: Thanks a lot barak, your reply was valuable n yes this works.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in while loop

```
boolean isSuccessful = false;
while(!isSuccessful){
   try{
     // do whatever you want
     isSuccessful = true;
   }catch(Exception e){
     // Exception so lets do it again
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Karna, your reply was valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new method with the xpath as argument and with a `try-catch` block in which you call `driver.findElement`.
Use this method instead of direct call to `driver.findElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of logic you can introduce to re-execute your `try-catch` as example one approach - `do-while` loop, where check in the loop condition that try is executated or not!

```
boolean reLoop = false;
do{
   try{
       // your code
   }catch(Exception ex){
      // handle your exception
      reLoop = true;
   }
}while(tryExecuted);
```

One important thing to consider that is `infinite-loop`, if your try is getting fail every time, In that specific case, consider the maximum number of `try` block should execute.

```
boolean reLoop = false;
int loopMaxCount = 3; // assumed maximum number of re looping 
int loopCont = 0; 
do{
   loopCont++;
   try{
       // your code
   }catch(Exception ex){
      // handle your exception
      if(loopCont < loopMaxCount) // It blocks infinite looping
           reLoop = true;
   }
}while(tryExecuted);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Subhrajyoti, your reply was valuable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of going back from `catch` to `try` block.

You will have to redesign your code - either wrap each `findElement()` method in separate `try/catch` blocks or use a loop as advised in other answers. (I guess in your code there will be two loops - second one will iterate through your all xpath arguments like: `"//td/div/div/div/a"` etc.).